# unity2d: Destroy method not working when i try to destroy a game object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

(this is not the whole code) when i test the script in the console it says: LEVEL2 UNLOCKED meaning that it works but when i try to use the destroy method it doesn't destroy the level2lock gameobject.

```
 if (PlayerPrefs.GetString("level2unlocked") == "true")
     {
         Debug.Log("LEVEL2 UNLOCKED");
         Destroy(level2lock);
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

Is 'level2lock' of the type GameObject, or is it a reference to a script attached to the GameObject.

So for example:

```
private LevelLockComponent level2lock;

private void DestroyLevelLockMethod()
{
    Destroy(level2lock.gameObject);
}
```

LevelLockComponent would be a script attached to the level2lock GameObject.

I hope this helps.

**Update**

Hi Drin,

I see, I've just written this simple implementation for destroying a GameObject that has been assigned in the editor.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GameObjectKiller : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject otherGameObject;

    private void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            Destroy(otherGameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

This destroys the 'otherGameObject' from the hierarchy when the A button is pressed.

I would also recommend looking at the Unity Tutorial for using 'Destroy' here: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/scripting/destroy

Comment: The level2lock variable is a public gameobject type, and i drag and drop the wall that blocks the player for going to the 2nd level, The problem is that i don't know how to use correctly the destroy method i want after the player finishes the first level(which is working because the level 2 unlocked text shows on the console), i tried to use the destroy method as seen above but i failed because the wall that blocks that player wasn't destroyed even though the text is shown, thats the problem.

Comment: I have tried that and it failed, but i will check those tutorials, thanks.